# Reading integers from scanner to array Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, count

i'm having problems with a simple exercise, i need to create a  method
readArray
that should read (using a scanner)
n
integers and return an array of length
n
storing the integers in the order they were read. Before reading integers, the method should print
n
to indicate how many integers are expected. The method main should be created in a way that `x` , `y` and `z` are produced by calls to read array

I am getting a compilation error "The method readArray(int) in the type ReadCompareArrays is not applicable for the arguments ()" how should I correct the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class ReadCompareArrays {
    public static int[] readArray(int n)
    {
        System.out.println("Insert 3 integers");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = s.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[count];
        return array;
    }
    public static boolean equalArrays (int [] a, int [] b) 
    {
        boolean result = true;  
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == b[i++] && a.length == b.length) { 
                    result = true;
                }
                else {result = false;}
            }
        return result;
    }   
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] x = readArray();
        int[] y = readArray();
        int[] z = readArray();
        System.out.print(equalArrays(x,y));
        System.out.print(equalArrays(y,z));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: it doesn't work i would like to know why

Comment: edited the question so that is easier to understand it

Comment: How does it "not work"?  What inputs?  What outputs?  What errors?

Comment: Your method readArray is wrong. `int count = s.nextInt();` allow the user to input only 1 integer, and `int[] array = new int[count];` instantiate an array of integer with the size `count` (if the user input 1000, you're gonna have an array of size 1000), but it is still empty.

Comment: "The method readArray(int) in the type ReadCompareArrays is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: So you have a **compilation error**.  Why didn't you say so?   The problem is NOT that your program doesn't work.  The problem is that your program doesn't compile!

Comment: I edited the question in order to make it clearer; sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Your readArray method is wrong. It just instantiates the array with how many elements you set count up to and then just returns it, you also need to read the elements before returning the array. Also the equalArrays can be much simpler.
 What the code should look like is similar to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class ReadCompareArrays {
    public static int[] readArray()
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("hoW many integeres do you want in the array?");
        int count = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("count is: " + count);
        int[] array = new int[count];
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        array[i] = s.nextInt();
        return array;
    }
        public static boolean equalArrays (int [] a, int [] b) 
        {
            if(Arrays.equals(a,b))
               return true;
            return false;
        }   
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            int[] x = readArray();
            int[] y = readArray();
            int[] z = readArray();
            System.out.print(equalArrays(x,y));
            System.out.print(equalArrays(y,z));
        }
    }
```

Comment: While it may be a valid answer, you did not point his mistakes, plus the `equalArray()' method could be much smaller.

Comment: if i try it like this, it never uses the main which should print a boolean; have you got any idea on why that doesn't work?

Comment: @JoeRamundo The main should actually print two booleans, because the equalArrays is used two times. I don't see any reason why it woudn't work, could you tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: @GeorgeCernat I'm not getting any errors, but when i input the size of the array, it just states that the count = that integer but it never prints the two booleans

Comment: @JoeRamundo You need to input the number of integer you want in your array, and after the messag  `countis : x`, you have to input your integer. For example : `count is : 3`, then you can input 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @Asew i think i have got that, it just doesn't print out the boolean, i'll try to figure it out on my own. Thank you

Comment: Thank you both very much

Comment: @JoeRamundo what was the issue?

Comment: @GeorgeCernat it didnt print out the two booleans results